# Saving defaultdict(list) to a csv file

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I've been trying to save my dictionary to a csv file.  So I want it to look something like this:

```
Subject                           value1   concussion
network3_UCA_0073_01_(0, 1)        0.57     no 
network3_UCA_0073_02_(0, 1)        0.64     no 
network3_UCA_0073_03_(0, 1)        0.59     no 
network3_UCA_0075_01_(0, 1)        0.69     no
```

The dictionary looks like this:

```
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{'network3_UCA_0073_01_(0, 1)': [(0.57, 'no')]}
{'network3_UCA_0073_02_(0, 1)': [(0.64, 'no')]}
{'network3_UCA_0073_03_(0, 1)': [(0.59, 'no')]}
{}
{}
{'network3_UCA_0075_01_(0, 1)': [(0.69, 'no')]}
{'network3_UCA_0075_02_(0, 1)': [(0.62, 'no')]}
{'network3_UCA_0075_03_(0, 1)': [(0.57, 'no')]}
{'network3_UCA_0076_01_(0, 1)': [(0.38, 'no')]}
{'network3_UCA_0076_02_(0, 1)': [(0.60, 'no')]}
{'network3_UCA_0076_03_(0, 1)': [(0.68, 'no')]}
{'network3_UCA_0077_01_(0, 1)': [(0.64, 'no')]}
{'network3_UCA_0077_02_(0, 1)': [(0.58, 'no')]}
{'network3_UCA_0077_03_(0, 1)': [(0.48, 'no')]}
```

The code I've been using to achieve this looks like the following (but unfortunately it hasn't been working):

```
with open(dirforR , 'a') as f:                                         
    writer = csv.writer(f)      
    writer.writerow(['Subject', 'value1', 'concussion'])                             

    for row in sorted_combined:                                        
        #print row[0]                                                   

        l = [row[0]]                                                   
        l.append(row[1][0])                                            
        l.append(row[1][1])                                            
        writer.writerow(l)
```

I'm not sure if its because the dictionary's key's are separated by \n , but any help would be greatly appreciated.  I've tried to figure it out with no hope.

Thanks for your help. I hope to hear back soon . 
*********EDIT***********

I realized that this is no ordinary dictionary, I actually have it set to:

```
sorted_combined = defaultdict(list)
```

the reason for this is because I was merging two dictionaries together and this was the only way I was able to go about it..
Now I'm not quite sure how to move my dictionary list to a csv file.

Sorry this got a little messy.

***EDIT2 ***this is the code that was used to make my defaultdict list called: network_combined

```
network3 = defaultdict(list)    
combined_MDD = {key : (MDD_network3[key], MDD_network3_yesno[key]) for key 
in MDD_network3}                                                                   
combined_HC = {key : (HC_network3[key], HC_network3_yesno[key]) for key in HC_network3}
for k, v in chain(combined_MDD.items(), combined_HC.items()):             
     network3[k].append(v)                                                
sorted_combined = {k:v for k,v in network3.items() if k.endswith('(0, 1)')}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use csv's dictionary writer for this, simply do a:

```
import csv
csv.DictWriter(open("path/to/writefile.csv","wb"),fieldnames=dict_to_write[dict_to_write.keys()[0]].keys(),delimiter=","")
```

alternatively you can use pandas as a more easier option:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(dict_to_write).to_csv("file.csv")
```

for you particular use case, assuming the sample you have given is in a file:

```
import pandas as pd
with open("dictionary.txt","r") as file:
    raw_d=file.read().splitlines()
    raw_d=[eval(x) for x in raw_d if len(x)>2]
pd.DataFrame([(k,v[0][0],v[0][1]) for x in raw_d for k,v in x.items()]).to_csv("converted_dict.csv")
```

Comment: Hi @Inder, thank you for your response.. But this won't work either. I just tried it. Maybe it won't work because my dictionary is printing each key line by line (not sure why) instead of being separated by commas.  I'm not sure how to fix this. Any idea how I can go about it?

Comment: Thanks @Inder I was just wondering where in the updated answer you provided should I input the defaultdict(list)? it is represented by  name `dict`. This information is not in a file.

Comment: @so `print (dict)` looks like your sample??? it is a variable that outputs your sample?? it's a nested dictionary?

Comment: I added more code to clarify how I got to this.  But I replaced dict variable name with sorted_combined.  I made a mistake with naming.  So I'm working with a defaultdictionary(list) called sorted_combined.  I showed the steps as to how I got it.

Answer (score 1):

With some editing I think i was able to work with your example

```
with open(dirforR , 'a') as f:                                         
writer = csv.writer(f)      
writer.writerow(['Subject', 'value1', 'concussion'])                             

for row in sorted_combined:                                        
    if len(row)==0:
        pass
    else:
      l=[val[0] for val in row.items()]
      for value in list([val[0] for val in row.values()][0]):
          l.append(value)
    writer.writerow(l)
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much! it actually works :)  But just a small followup question, in my csv file I'm getting something that looks like this: 
`network3_QNS_0044_01_(0, 1) 0.498 no
network3_QNS_0044_02_(0, 1) 0.452 
network3_QNS_0044_02_(0, 1) 0.452 no
network3_QNS_0044_03_(0, 1) 0.613 ` so it seems like its repeating the same subject twice each time... once with the second column one without it. Do you know why this might be happening and how to fix it? @TavoGLC

Comment: Perhaps in the second column instead of 'no' or 'yes' you have an empty string '' causing that behavior. Try to check all the data before the dictionary generation.

Comment: you're right. I realized I do have empty strings but I don't know how to not include them.  I thought maybe this part of the code:` if len(row)==0` would solve that problem.  Do you know what I could add to this code to fix this issue?

Comment: Try adding an if statement over the dictionary generation, somehing like `{key : (MDD_network3[key], MDD_network3_yesno[key]) for key 
in MDD_network3 if len(MDD_network3_yesno[key])!=0} ` for both dictionaries